# How to get current seconds left to complete hour?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get how many seconds are remaining to complete an hour. No matter which what time it is?

if its 05:01:00 then it should give 3540 seconds
and if its 11:58:40 then it gives 80 seconds and so on. I try to find it on google but could not able to find it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do if it's called exactly at the top of the hour? Return the current hour, or the next hour, which will be exactly 60 minutes later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSCalendar` has got methods to do that kind of date math:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar =  [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
// find next date where the minutes are zero
NSDate *nextHour = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:now matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:0 options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
// get the number of seconds between now and next hour
NSDateComponents *componentsToNextHour = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:now toDate:nextHour options:0];
NSLog(@"%ld", componentsToNextHour.second);
```

Comment: Thanks and highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

@Vadian's answer is very good. (voted)

It requires iOS 8 or later however.

There are other ways you could do this using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` that would work with older OS versions.

You could use `componentsFromDate` to get the month, day, year, and hour from the current date, then increment the hour value and use the `NSCalendar` method `dateFromComponents:` to convert your to adjusted components back to a date.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-02-03 00:00:00 +0000"];

NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Fill in with the correct times and dates to get the difference in seconds

Edit: An alternative method is to work out the currenthour and return as an integer. Then add one to the NSInteger returned as below (you will have to make sure to handle the case where it is after midnight though!)

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
```

Comment: i dont know the both times, i know only the current time and i have to find out how many seconds need to complete that hour?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039

Comment: Return the current hour, then calculate the current hour + 1- (NSInteger)currentHour
{
    // In practice, these calls can be combined
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

    return [components hour];
}

Comment: - (NSInteger)currentHour
    {
        // In practice, these calls can be combined
       NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar     components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    
    return [components hour];
    }

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. You are feeding in 2 constant dates created from date strings. The OP asked how to calculate the number of seconds from an arbitrary NSDate to the next "top of the hour".